# Is there a way to place a hyperlink inside a textInput with Shiny R

Tags: r, url, shiny, textinput

For a project I'm currently working on, I want to place a hyperlink inside a textInput box using shiny R. When using the following script in R my html code gets shown inside the textInput box instead of showing "Google homepage" as a clickable link.

```
test <- a("Google Homepage", href="https://www.google.com/")

runApp(
    list(ui = fluidPage(
         textInput("test", "test", test)
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session){
    })
)
```

Would it be possible to place a hyperlink inside a textInput box? Or only as a output value?

Comment: Not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823835/html-in-the-input-field-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stéphanie mentioned, this is not possible.
Because you include the a tag as value of an input element. If you look at the HTML you will see:

```
<input id="test" type="text" class="form-control shiny-bound-input" value="<a href=&quot;https://www.google.com/&quot;>Google Homepage</a>">
```

So if you just want a clickable link you dont need a `textInput`.
Just put the `a tag` in the `fluidPage`:

```
test <- a("Google Homepage", href="https://www.google.com/")

runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    test
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
  })
)
```