# How can I highlight part of the text in material-ui TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to **Highlight** not **Select** part of the value in `TextField` component

Something like this

[image]

I tried having a `<span>` with a class in the value prop but that showed `[object Object]` instead.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value

Answer (score 0):

Material UI Textfield component is basically made up of a html input component.

the Textfield "value" prop will be reflected as html input element's value

[HTML in the input field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823835/html-in-the-input-field-value)

Comment: So does this mean there is no way to highlight part of the TextField value?

Comment: I have used reach text editor components to show formatting text, But i dont know if it fits your use case

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to highlight**, but we need to pre-parse the text in to html,

**Warning!!** Must be careful about the source of the text.

*npm install html-react-parser*

```
var parse = require('html-react-parser');
<Typography > {parse(props.text)}</Typography>
```

**Example:** props.text = "This should render your html"

Comment: How is this helping? You do not talk about TextFields nor inputs, and we don't want to parse HTML here, we want to highlight a part of the text in a Mui TextField.

Comment: this was honestly the only useful solution. It is helpful because you can create HTML elements at will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use editable **MUI Typography**,

like the example in this stackoverflow Question: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195072/seamlessly-switch-between-a-text-element-and-a-text-input-in-material-ui)

then wrap it with  from [react-mark](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mark.js)

```
const [search,setSearch]=useState('abc');

return ( <Marker mark={search}>
        <Typography contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true} gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
          {title}
        </Typography>
 </Marker>)
```

The search text will be marked, and the typography is editable.

Hope it help some one!